# Class FIRApp is implemented in both One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am developing a Cocoa Framework for implementing some Firebase Cloud Messaging functionality. I installed pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’ inside this framework.
The problem is that when I added to a single view application, it did not work because Firebase pod was not installed in that project, so some errors were thrown because of this (in the public headers of the framework I was exporting), so my solution was to install pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’ inside my. App too, so I get rid of this errors.
The problem is that when I execute this (On a simulator), the output console output errors like this

Class FIRAnalyticsConfiguration is implemented in both “Some path” and “Other path”

Class FIRApp is implemented in both “Some path” and “Other path”

And so on ...

I been researching about this, and I found that pods in dynamic framework target are also linked to app target.

But I’ve tried to remove linked pods in my framework so when I import it this will not be longer linked, but this is not working.

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I also have a normal Xcode project that imports/embeds our new framework/SDK which includes Firebase and it can't initialize: `The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized`